# Limiting row returns in table column search

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to look up some data from a table in Excel, using the following formula

```
=IF(Table_People[Polity]=lookup_PolityRuler, Table_People[Name],"")
```

This does return only the rows that I want as a dynamic range. However, it also returns blank rows where the other data was (see below):

[image: Blank Rows in Lookup]

How can I (/ is it possible to) get just the rows from the data using a formula such as this? The solution I am looking for can be summarised in the following pseudocode:

```
for each cell in [col Table_People[Polity]]
    if [cell in col Table_People[Polity]] contains [value in lookup cell]  Then
        add [cell in same row in col Table_People[Name]] to [Dynamic Array]
```

The content of Table_People is:

[image]

and the range `lookup_PolityRuler` is pointing at cell `A2` i.e. adjacent to the cell with the formula in it.

Comment: Please [edit] your post & upload complete data set from Table & possibly the named range i.e. `lookup_PolityRuler` since the info U have passed is not sufficient to test the command what you have tried so far !!

Comment: @RajeshS There you are, hope the image is ok. This is a toy example as I am playing around trying to simulate a database with lookups in Excel.

Comment: ,, what are data for `lookup_PolityRuler` and example since not in the shown Table !

Comment: What you are trying is possible using an Array (CSE),,, (if u r looking for multiple rows to return) or Lookup Formula like VLOOKUP/INDEX & MATCH in case only one record at a time!! One like this `=INDEX(TablePeople[Name],MATCH(PoRuler,TablePeople[Polity],0))`

Comment: Confirm through comments then I'll show you that how to achieve those records.

Comment: The problem is that formula only returns the first valid match. I want all returns in a dynamic array.

To clarify this example, lookup_PolityRuler is "Roman Empire" as seen in cell "A2" of the first image.

Comment: @RajeshS Sorry, I misunderstood what you were saying. Yes, I think that is what I want. The match index does return the first value from the table with the correct entry, so if you could look through all the table with skip values you have already added to the array that would work.

Comment: Check my post & confirm whether is working or not !!

Answer (score 0):

*I do believe that this will help you, and the best part is that both suggested methods works with higher as well lower versions of Excel.*

[image]

- *I've shown two possible methods where first command only returns one
  value/data at a time and second one returns multiple rows.*

**How it works:**

- Range AA2 is Named Range `PoRuler` & is editable.
- Formula to get one Name at a time in cell `W11`.

  =INDEX(TablePeople[Name],MATCH(PoRuler,TablePeople[Polity],0))
- Cell `X11` has an array (CSE) formula returns multiple Name.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(TablePeople[Name], SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($AA$2, TablePeople[Polity]), ROW(TablePeople)-MIN(ROW(TablePeople))+1), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),"")}
  ```
- Finish formula in X11 with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.
- Cell references in the formula are adjustable.

Comment: What is `ROW(A1)` and `COLUMN(A1)` referring to? I cannot get this formula to work on my dataset and not confident in understanding what exactly it is doing.

Comment: Both refers start of data set the formula collects and my dear @GalacticPonderer how the formula is working can be seen using the screen shot I've attached,, the formula filters & pulls NAMEs have Polity ROMAN,, !! **Read carefully HOW it works** .

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

use the `Filter` function from Excel's Array function.

The solution that worked in this case was:

```
=FILTER(Table_People[Name],Table_People[Polity] = lookup_PolityRuler)
```

Comment: Yeah you are write,,but remember FILTER is an Dynamic array formula doing same what INDEX & MATCH did,,, but FILTER works with higher versions only & both of formula I've suggested  works with higher as well lower version also. Anyways pleas confirm whether are useful for you or not??

Comment: I have tried to get your formula working but cannot at the moment.